# Using Change of Variables to get the distribution function

Tags: distributions

I have a random variable, call it $X$. This is a uniform random variable that is defined on the $[0,1]$ interval. Now consider its transformation $Z$ defined as:  $$Z=klog\times(X)$$ where $k$  is a negative real number. I now wish to calculate the distribution function of $Z$. This is what I have done. Now, by definition, $$F_{Z}(Z)\equiv Pr(z\leq Z)=Pr(klog(X)\leq Z)$$   $$=Pr(logX\geq Z/k)=Pr(X\geq 10^Z/k)=1-Pr(X\leq 10^Z/k)$$  $$=1-(10^Z)/k$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have a few errors:

- Usually we use the capitol $Z$ to represent the random variable, so $F_Z(Z) = Pr(Z \le z)$.
- Your end result is a distribution function, you need to differentiate this to obtain the density
- The inverse of $\log$ is $\exp$. In statistics, $\log$ is always $\log_e$ not $\log_{10}$.

Comment: Thanks..I agree with the first two points. This variable was generated in a programming language, so I am not sure if we are talking about the natural log (depends what the term "log" corresponds to in the specific language)

Comment: @ChinG well since you're posting on a statistics site, you should write base 10. It's just an exponential variable either way, but your mean is not necessarily $1/k$.